# Concatenate rows in pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-apply

I am trying to concatenate the rows that do not start with a specific character ('[') to the closest row that starts with it. I have read the txt file as following:

[image: start df],

and I expect to get

[image: end df].

Comment: Please copy/paste your data/expected output as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Let us do

```
s=df.groupby(df.text.str.startswith('[').cumsum()).agg(' ',join)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str[0]` to check for the first character, then `cumsum` to mark the blocks:

```
df['text'].groupby(df['text'].str[0].eq('[').cumsum()).agg(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
text
1            [aaa] sss
2    [bbb] mmm fff ppp
3        [iii] rrr qqq
4            [ggg] kkk
Name: text, dtype: object
```